# Resizing elements on formResize in delphi

Tags: delphi, resize

I'm currently trying to resize components in my form but i can't figure it out how it works. I've tried OnResize and OnCanResize event but it won't change my component heigh or widht.

What i did until now is adding like fixed values to my heigh when the user is resizing but it doesn't resize the given component.

For example:

In my FormResize even i have something similar to:

```
procedure myform.FormResize(Sender TObject);
var
    width: integer;
begin
    width := grid.Width +100; //yes it only grows but it doesn't even work
    grid.setBounds(grid.Left,grid.Top,width,grid.height);
end;
```

This doesn't work.

I also tried changing direcly with `grid.Width := grid.Width +100` but it doesn't work either

I tried putting the same code in CanResize but same issue. I've tried with break points if it's the right event and if the procedure is being executed when i resize and yes it is. So i guess i missed something. My purpose is to resize the grid to keep the ratio to my form when ever a user resize/maximize the form.

So what is the proper way to resize a component?

Thank you.

## DFM

```
  object BDDTool: TBDDTool
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'BDD Manager'
  ClientHeight = 303
  ClientWidth = 680
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = mMainMenu
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  OnCloseQuery = FormCloseQuery
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnResize = FormResize
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object pnlFileManager: TPanel
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 665
    Height = 289
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    TabOrder = 0
    object Label1: TLabel
      Left = 156
      Top = 263
      Width = 86
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Primary key color:'
    end
    object Label2: TLabel
      Left = 364
      Top = 263
      Width = 86
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Foreign key color:'
    end
    object sgFilePreview: TStringGrid
      Left = 143
      Top = 23
      Width = 514
      Height = 234
      Align = alCustom
      ColCount = 1
      Enabled = False
      FixedCols = 0
      RowCount = 2
      TabOrder = 0
      OnDrawCell = sgFilePreviewDrawCell
      OnMouseDown = sgFilePreviewMouseDown
      ColWidths = (
        64)
      RowHeights = (
        24
        24)
    end
    object btnConnectToDB: TButton
      Left = 0
      Top = 32
      Width = 137
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Connect to DB'
      Enabled = False
      TabOrder = 1
      OnClick = btnConnectToDBClick
    end
    object btnCreateTabIncK: TButton
      Left = 0
      Top = 94
      Width = 137
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Create table (inc keys)'
      Enabled = False
      TabOrder = 2
      OnClick = btnCreateTabIncKClick
    end
    object btnCreateTabGuidK: TButton
      Left = 0
      Top = 125
      Width = 137
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Create table (guid keys)'
      Enabled = False
      TabOrder = 3
    end
    object btnAscFk: TButton
      Left = 0
      Top = 156
      Width = 137
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Associate foreign keys'
      Enabled = False
      TabOrder = 4
      OnClick = btnAscFkClick
    end
    object pnlFKColor: TPanel
      Left = 456
      Top = 263
      Width = 81
      Height = 18
      TabOrder = 5
    end
    object btnDeconnectDB: TButton
      Left = 0
      Top = 63
      Width = 137
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Deconnect from DB'
      Enabled = False
      TabOrder = 6
      OnClick = btnDeconnectDBClick
    end
  end
  object pnlPKColor: TPanel
    Left = 256
```

Comment: Sidenote, `Width` is a bad name for a variable. Well, it's good for explaining what it does, but it *conflicts* with the form's `Width` property (not really). What is the *proper* way is hard to say without knowing your layout. If I get right your layout (and the way you want to resize the grid), I would call *proper* using anchors.

Comment: I changed my variable's name but it doesn't work either :(

Comment: If you want to resize your grid with the form, set the `Anchors` property to `[akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]` (in the IDE set all 4 `Anchors` property *subvalues* to True), then remove your code from the `OnResize` event and relax ;-)

Comment: What is akLEft,akTop,akRight and bottom? Do i define it like  `grid.Anchors[] ` ?

Comment: If you set an Anchor like, [akTop, akRight] then the component will be "glued" to the Top and Right side of its container (parent) component. So if the parent get resized the component will automatically move with the parent's right side. So the space between the parent's right edge and the component's right edfe remains the same. If you set it to [akLeft,akRight] it will resize it horizontally only. If you set it to [akRight,akBottom] then it will remain in the Bottom Right corner of its parent.

Comment: I did this in FormResize: `grid.Anchors[akLeft,akTop,akRight,akBottom]` it says `Array type required`

Comment: This does correct the problem: `grid.Anchors := [akLeft,akTop,akRight,akBottom]grid.Anchors[akLeft,akTop,akRight,akBottom] but it doesn't resize the grid :(

Comment: Set it in the Object inspector, not in code and remove the Form's OnResize event. And it's probably won't work because your Grid is on a Panel and the grid will resize according to that, not to the form. As I wrote before, the Anchors will resize the component to its PARENT not to the Form.

Comment: Oh nice! I've put anchors on form create to both panel and grid and it works :D. Is there a way to get sicky buttons to the grid or do i have to make a new topic for this? And if you want post your answer in answers so i can accept it and others can see it

Comment: I think you can do the buttons with Anchors too. For example, if you want to make them under the grid, just put them there and set them Anchors to [akBottom, akLeft].

Comment: Also look at the Alignment property of your components - I would suggest you open a new project and slap some TPanels on the mainform and see how the panels behave with alLeft, alRight, alTop, alBottom & alClient. You might be pleasantly surprised at how nicely that works.  You can then add buttons to the panels with anchors ...

Comment: Yeah i've check this but it's align the whole grid at the bottom or top or left. I probably missed the one that autosizes it. Thank you for your suggestion Hugh

Comment: @user28470: If you use Delphi 2006 or newer you can combine the Align with Margins.

Comment: Oh i see, the margins would keep the space between the form and the component and the align would keep it in the same place. Didn't know that. I'm learning delphi on the fly so i ask a lot of things ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you grid's Align property. If it's set something else to alNone then the resizing won't work as excepted.

Instead of OnResize try to use Anchors. Anchors will tell the component where its edges will "glued" inside its parent. If you set an empty Anchor [] it will remains always centered, if you set it to [akBottom, akRight] it will remains in the Bottom Right corner of its parent when the parent component is resized. If you set it to [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom] then it will resize in vertically and horizontally too and maintains space between the parent's edges and its own.

If you use Anchors, you doesn't need the OnResize event for that.

Comment: Mycomponent is a TStringGrid component. I've set it to alNone (it was on custom) but doesn't work :/

Comment: I4ve searched on the internet how to resize a StringGrid. All i can find is how to resize columns but i don't need this

Comment: Please provide more information. Update your post with the StringGrid's definition (copy it from the DFM file).

Comment: Here you have the dfm. Why do you need it?

Comment: I need this because I can check if something wrong with the component definition, but I don't see any problem with it. Did you try to do the resizing in a button click for example. Does it work here?

Comment: @Fenistil, there is a problem. The parent is not resized.

Comment: @TLama, I see, but if the parent is big enough you can resize the grid inside it. The question was asked because the grid won't resize at all. I think if it works, but flow out of the panel, it should be noticed, but there is no information about it.

Comment: @Fenistil, then check how the layout looks like. The grid overflows the panel width already. How would one could see it bigger if the parent is not resized ?

Comment: @TLama, there is a 8px space on the right side:
Panel.Width = 665
Grid.Left = 143 + Grid.Width = 514 = 657

Comment: @Fenistil, I'm sorry, my bad. Well, so there were 8 pixels of extra space. Still, missing parent resize was the actual problem anyway. Besides, be careful when saying *maintains space between the parent's edges* since that's the work for `Margins`.

Comment: @TLama, I just tried to explain the anchor's working as simply as I can. However, in newer Delphi version, where Margins are present the full explanation should take care about it, you're right, but in this situation I think it wasn't as important.